# How to control text resize rate in HTML page

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

We have designed an application which has two frames. First frame have displays available menu list in it and second frame have the menu content displayed in it. We have designed our pages and style sheets so that the page text content is re sizable using View > Text Size feature of IE.

Is there any re size controlling factor which we can specify for HTML elements or style sheets? Because when we re size the text content, the factor with which the menu list changes in far more than the menu content frame.

Note: All the margins , borders, font size etc., are specified using em.

Regards ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because because of the tables which we were using. It was increasing the re-size factor for reasons of which i am not aware of. instead now we are trying to use div tags and achieve the required structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control the text size forced from the IE menu options.

You could implement your own font size control though using Javascript or jQuery.